# Need to secure WCF data, but just for one section

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl

I have a WCF Service setup using BasicHttpBinding, now I need to make a section where I will allow users to upload a file.  This needs to be secure, so we are thinking of using SSL for transfer from website to WCF.  Does anyone know if I need to create another WCF Service just for the SSL piece or can it all be in one WCF Service, part of it being BasicHTTPBinding and the other part being the SSL piece, as we don't want to use SSL for all calls, just a few related to the file upload.

Otherwise is there anothe way to approach this?  Like possibly encrypt the file via some encryption method on the website side and then send it over we could try that if that's recommended, so no SSL just sending the encrypted file to WCF to store on the server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need 2 WCF services with seperate contracts, but they can be hosted onn the same site.

Configure the one that you want to use SSL with a binding that has "Transport Security".